# Why router XBee does not receive frame from coordinator XBee in API mode

Tags: api, xbee, zigbee

I have two XBee S2 modules which are connected to PC with the help of XBee adapter boards. I configured the XBees in API mode (one is API coordinator; another one is API Router) using X-CTU software. 
I can transmit frames from Router and can receive at Coordinator, but I can't receive any data at Router if I send a frame from coordinator or router. In AT mode I can transmit and receive data  correctly.

In Router,

```
DL:13A200
DH:40E423FF
PAN ID:1234
```

In Coordinator,

```
DL:13A200
DH:40E42411
PAN ID:1234
```

Baud rate: 9600 in both

What is the problem behind it?

Answer (score 1):

How are you constructing your API frames.  As I recall, you should only use one of the addresses.  Either the 64-bit EUI or the 16-bit network address.  You need to use `0xFFFE` as the network address if you specify the 64-bit EUI.  Use all 0xFF for the 64-bit EUI if you're using 16-bit addressing.

If that doesn't help, post a dump of the API frames your using -- both the working frame for router to coordinator and the non-working frame from coordinator to router.

Also, are you getting any Transmit Status frames on the coordinator that might indicate where your failure is?